# link working on localhost not working on deploy server

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a web page rendered by a link running in localhost, but it fails on deply server.

```
...
    //this is html page
    var view = document.createElement('a');
    $(view).addClass('btn btn-primary btn-sm')
    view.textContent = "Update";
    view.setAttribute('href', window.location.href+'/'+doc.id)
    //note : window.location.href = http://localhost:5000/<project>/app/home/
    ...`

    //this is server side
        app.get('/home/:id', (req, res) => {
            res.render('viewData', {
                params : req.params.id
            })
        })
    exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

its render:

```
app.get('*', (req,res) => res.send('Page not found'))
```

Comment: sory for my bad english

Comment: did you check at the fullpath of your page on deploy server? If it is not rendered through passages from root directory it could be different and you need to update it

Comment: @cccnrc the link is in right path when deploy, but the page dosen't rendered. it's show page not found. 
thx for replay.

Comment: see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely misleading the path of the file that changed from your `localhost` to deploy server.

You says that: `window.location.href = http://localhost:5000/<project>/app/home/`

change it to the REAL actual path of your app, you can get it from PHP via: 
 `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` (and add sub-folders from this path if necessary)

And it should work!

Comment: https://iconproject-f66b2.web.app/app/home/HkY2MzBeEwhd4TUXwZhn i'm on the right path but the server dont render right page, u can visit my app sir https://iconproject-f66b2.web.app/app. and i using firebase callback functions.
thx