# Gatsby JS <Link> element in header navigation functional in localhost but not when generating static files

Tags: gatsby

After deploying the website (i.e., running gatsby build and copying everything from the public folder into the webserver WWW folder), I could not navigate from my home page to the other subpages of my website using the Gatsby Links in my navigation. The links work on the localhost but not on the webserver. Below is the code that I have in my header.js file. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: When I run my code on the localhost:8000 server I can navigate between my Gatsby pages using the navigation bar, so like going from index  (localhost:8000) to the contact page (localhost:8000/contact) for example. However, when I use gatsby build to generate static files and open my index.html files in the public folder, the navigating between pages functionality goes away. So like say I'm on the home page (file:///.../website/public/index.html). If I click the Contact link, it'll go to file:///.../contact instead of file:///.../website/public/contact/index.html. The StackOverflow link below talked about there being an issue with sourcing my files from the root but I'm not sure if that is the problem in my case.

NOTE: I looked at this StackOverflow page but I'm not sure if it applies to my case: [link working on localhost not working on deploy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57282310/link-working-on-localhost-not-working-on-deploy-server).
EDIT: I also looked at this article on the GatsbyJS website: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/preparing-for-deployment/
I think maybe adding a path prefix will help but I'm not sure if that would apply to my case, or how to source the right path in my package-lock.json file.

```
<nav id="collapse" class="navbar-collapse">
                <ul className="nav-list nav-list-right">
                    <li>
                      <Link className="link" to="/publications/">
                        Publications
                      </Link>
                    </li>                    
                    <li>
                        <Link class="link" to="/research/">Research</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link class="link" to="/team/">Team</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link class="link" to="/director/">Director</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link class="link" to="/contact/">Contact</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What's the output?

Comment: Navigation works fine in development (e.g., clicking Contact from Index will go from localhost:8000/ to localhost:8000/contact) but when preparing for deployment/generating static files for my website there's a sourcing issue (e.g., clicking Contact will go from file:///.../public/index.html to file:////contact and won't load the correct page).

Comment: Share your `/pages` folder structure please

Comment: @FerranBuireu https://i.imgur.com/h5oP7Pw.png

Comment: What version of Gatsby have you run?

Comment: @FerranBuireu Gatsby CLI version: 2.13.0
Gatsby version: 2.24.85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've read so far in Gatsby's GitHub regarding similar issues, seems to be related to some recent changes that they have done in the `location` and `window` providers.

Try downgrading `2.24.65` which seems to be bug-free.

Remove the cache, your `node_modules` folder, and your check your lock files to see if Gatsby is in the correct version.

References:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27196

Comment: I did all the things you said and looked at the reference link. It turned out my issue had to do with how I was installing my pathPrefix. This article also really helped me out: [Gatsby Links failure after deployment on github pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62318100/gatsby-links-failure-after-deployment-on-github-pages?rq=1) Thank you so much!